# Probability of a positive outcome from 2 events that have a 2% chance of a positive outcome

Tags: probability

Apologies for my lack of maths jargon and terminology.

This seems like a very simple problem to solve. I need a formula to determine the following;

> If event A has a 2% chance of success
>
> If event B has a 2% chance of success
>
> What is the chance that A and B are a success?

The 2% comes from a dice roll, or rather several dice rolls. But it is the chance that the right dice are thrown to give a positive outcome. E.g. a 4+ then a 6 and then another 6. This is on the same dice and they are independent events.

My question is if I had 10 dice, each with a 2% chance of success, what are the chances that;

- 1 of the 10 is a success
- 2 of the 10 is a success
- 3 of the 10 is a success
- 4 of the 10 is a success
- 5 of the 10 is a success
- 6 of the 10 is a success
- 7 of the 10 is a success
- 8 of the 10 is a success
- 9 of the 10 is a success
- 10 of the 10 is a success

10 could be any value though. Sometimes I might have 5 dice or 20 dice.

Comment: In your second scenario, specify if you mean "at least one" or "exactly one".

Comment: Are the events independent?

Comment: I have updated the question to try and answer these questions and give some more context.

Comment: Look up the binomial distribution @JakeN. You'll find the exact formula you're looking for and everything.

Comment: You might look up some texts on basic probability.  The chapter on probability in [Diez and Cetinkaya-Rundel, 2013, OpenIntro Statistics, 3rd.](https://www.openintro.org/stat/textbook.php?stat_book=os) might be useful.  A pdf of the book can downloaded free.